# Query in Oracle(select, sum and count using join)

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

Table 1 :- Registration table

```
Date_phy       |Name      |Address  |Diseases   |Mob    | Advance   |Code
12 March, 2017 |Navneet   |Delhi    |Fever      |12345  | 1000      |2
12 March, 2017 |Ashutosh  |Gurgaon  |fever      |4321   | 2000      |3
12 March, 2017 |Bitu      |Mumbai   |fever      |2345   | 1500      |4
15 March, 2017 |Rashmi    |pune     |fever      |34567  | 1600      |5
16 March, 2017 |komal     |jaipur   |fever      |43215  | 7000      |6
```

Table 2 :- Attendence Table

```
Code    |Name        |Date_phy
2       |Navneet     |13 March,2017
2       |Navneet     |14 March,2017
2       |Navneet     |15 March,2017
5       |Rashmi      |16 March,2017
6       |komal       |17 March,2017
```

Table 3:- Deposit Table

```
Code    |Amount   |Date_phy
2       |1000     |13 March,2017
2       |500      |14 March,2017
2       |500      |15 March,2017
5       |3000     |16 March,2017
6       |5000     |17 March,2017
```

I want following output in oracle.

```
Name     |Date of Joining    |Code  |Total Paid(advance+deposit) |Total Present
Navneet  |12 March,2017      |2     |3000                        |3
Ashutosh |12 March,2017      |3     |2000                        |0
Bitu     |12 March,2017      |4     |1500                        |0
Rashmi   |15 March,2017      |5     |4600                        |1
Komal    |16 March,2017      |6     |12000                       |1
```

I am not able to write a query. I have to merge three tables with sum and count function.
Tried every thing but failed. 
Could you please help me ?

Query tried:

```
SELECT pr.NAME, 
       pr.date_phy, 
       pr.disease 
FROM   physiofit_registration pr 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sum(amount) totalAmount 
                  FROM   physiofit_amt_deposit 
                  GROUP  BY code) pd 
              ON pr.code = pd.code 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(*) totalatten, 
                  FROM   physiofit_attendence 
                  GROUP  BY code) pa 
              ON pr.code = pa.code;
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried this :- SELECT  pr.name, pr.date_phy, pr.disease FROM physiofit_registration pr LEFT JOIN (SELECT  SUM(Amount) totalAmount FROM physiofit_amt_deposit GROUP   BY code) pd 
ON pr.code = pd.code LEFT JOIN (SELECT  COUNT(*) totalatten, FROM    physiofit_attendence GROUP  BY code) pa ON pr.code = pa.code;

Comment: I have also tried this as a example but not working :- select pr.name,pa.mycount from physiofit_registration pr inner join (select count(code) as mycount FROM physiofit_attendence pa group by code) on pr.code=pa.code; - @ShaikElias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
SELECT pr.NAME,
       pr.date_phy,
       pr.code,
       pd.totalAmount+pr.advance as TotalPaid,
pa.totalatten as TotalPresent
FROM   physiofit_registration pr
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT code,Sum(amount) totalAmount
                  FROM   physiofit_deposit
           group by code
                  ) pd
              ON (pr.code = pd.code)
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT code,Count(*) totalatten
                  FROM   physiofit_attendence
                  GROUP  BY code) pa
           ON pr.code = pa.code;
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much - @shaik Elias  - :)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it fixes your problem. Marking as answer will help those who land up on this problem from search engines.

Comment: I marked it as a answer. Thank You it is very usefull. it was very complex query.